# JCR locking on multi clustered environment

Tags: multithreading, locking, cluster-computing, jcr, jackrabbit

I have been struggling to come up with a working solution when it comes to adding content to JCR nodes executed in different instances of the same cluster.

It has been explained [here](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering#Concurrent_Write_Behavior) that "when multiple cluster nodes write to the same nodes, those nodes must be locked first".

Which i have done, but i still get stale item exceptions like below:

```
javax.jcr.InvalidItemStateException: Unable to update a stale item: item.save()
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.perform(ItemSaveOperation.java:262)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:91)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.save(ItemImpl.java:329)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionSaveOperation.perform(SessionSaveOperation.java:65)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:361)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:812)
```

I also follow the suggested approach on how to lock nodes [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/17_Locking.html), (see 17.10 Locks and Transactions)

here is simplified version of my code when it comes to lock procedures

```
    session.getRootNode().addNode("one").addMixin("mix:lockable");
    session.save();
    session.getWorkspace().getLockManager().lock("/one", true, true, 5000, session.getUserID());
    session.save();// usually it explodes here
    session.getNode("/one").addNode("two").addMixin("mix:lockable");
    session.save();
    session.getWorkspace().getLockManager().unlock("/one");
```

Please note this would be executed on two different instances (clustered) at the same time.

As you can see in my code above it explodes after i attempt to save the lock which was just added to the node, however this is recommendation that is stated in the [link](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/17_Locking.html) i shared earlier. 
I understand why it explodes, this is because two instances were trying to add lock on the same node. When a lock is added to a node it modifies the node by adding two properties (*jcr:lockOwner* and *jcr:lockIsDeep*), so if **instance 1** added lock then **instance 2** added lock, and **instance1** attempted to save then you get stale item, because **instance 2** modified the node by adding a lock to it... so how would i prevent this from happening?

Many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow found this topic and have checked your code, what do you wrong here is that you are obtaining a session based lock therefore your clustered repositories has not idea of the lock since its not applied to clustered node.

What you should have done instead is to do the following:

```
session.getWorkspace().getLockManager().lock("/one", true, false, 5000, session.getUserID());
```

More information can be found at:
https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering#Concurrent_Write_Behavior
Especially under limitations column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with `node.refresh(false)` to force the node to refresh his cache and get new modifications

Comment: when would you perform the refresh? just before save or before lock? also in documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Item.html#refresh(boolean)) it states that all changes will be cleared for the current session if refresh(false) is applied. But i think my problem is related to changes applied by other session?

Comment: Before the save. If the node is already modified, it will be unusable anyway.
But you maybe right, i had misunderstood the fact that the refresh actually  just "reset" all pending modification in the current ssession. I've never used Jackrabbit on a clustered environment to be honest